# Why do some variables automatically bind to other values in Elixir? Ex. case

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm in the process of learning Elixir and I was curious why the following occurs:

```
iex(4)> case {:one, :two} do
...(4)>   {:four, :five} ->
...(4)>     "This won't match"
...(4)>   {:one, x} ->
...(4)>     "This will match and bind `x` to `:two`"
...(4)>   _ ->
...(4)>     "This will match any value"
...(4)> end
"This will match and bind `x` to `:two`"
```

So if in this 'Pattern Matching' example, why does the empty variable `x` automatically bind to the atom `:two` and provide a positive match? `x` doesn't equal `:two` when this `case` is first run.

I'm just not grasping what exactly is going on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pattern matching in a clause (case or function) performs the same operation as `{:one, x} = {:one, :two}` (which is also pattern matching). In this second case it is obvious that you want to test if the 2 expressions match, and you want to bind the variable x if it was unbound previously. The only difference is that if the match fails in a clause (for example `{:four, :five} = {:one, :two}`) , it will try the next clause if any previous clause is throwing an exception.

It is a very powerful feature because it does a lot of operations with very few lines and keeps the code easy to read.

Comment: If you want to use the current value of x to pattern match against, use can use the pin operator: ^x http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971357/what-is-the-pin-operator-for-and-are-elixir-variables-mutable

Answer (score 3):

> `x` doesn't equal `:two` when this case is first run.

Exactly. `x` is an unbound variable, so it can match against anything (and will then be bound to what it matched). In this case, `{:one, x}` successfully matches `{:one, :two}` (since `x` can match anything), and since `x` was unbound, it can now be bound to `:two`.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. But I'm still wondering what causes `x` to bind to `:two:`? I understand that it can, but why is it necessary that it does? `x` could just remain an empty variable that doesn't match `:two`, could it not?

Comment: @reknirt: Do you mean, why is it necessary to bind variables to values in the first place?

Comment: Was looking back through this and I'd love for you to explain why it is indeed necessary to bind variables to values in the first place.